# How to get Opposite result of Regex.Split VB.NET?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have some string, like this one:`[H]GOODYEAR[/H] [H]TIRE[/H] &amp; RUBBER COMPANY`
I need to get words that inside [H] [/H] node inside this string.

I created this Regex Pattern: `\[H](.*?)\[\/H]`
I've tried to use Regex.Split Method to get this words. Here's my code:

```
Dim pattern As String = "\[H](.*?)\[\/H]" 
Dim input As String = "[H]GOODYEAR[/H] [H]TIRE[/H] &amp; RUBBER COMPANY"
Dim SearchedResult() As String = Regex.Split(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

But then I realized, that this `Split` gives me everything, which is not words I need.

My question: How to get correct words? Is that any way to `REVERSE` Regex pattern? Or any better way to get my result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `split`ting the string, you should use **Regex.**[Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

**Note:** I used inline modifiers `(?si)`, the `s` (*dotAll*) modifier which forces the dot `.` to match newline characters in case the nodes span across multiple lines, and the `i` modifier for case-insensitive matching.

```
Dim input As String = "[H]GOODYEAR[/H] [H]TIRE[/H] &amp; RUBBER COMPANY"
For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(input, "(?si)\[H](.*?)\[/H]")
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

**Output**

```
GOODYEAR
TIRE
```